# Data frame renaming columns

Tags: python, dataframe, rename

data sample from CSV file

```
Model,Displ,Cyl,Trans,Drive,Fuel,Cert Region,Stnd,Stnd Description,Underhood ID,Veh Class,Air Pollution Score,City MPG,Hwy MPG,Cmb MPG,Greenhouse Gas Score,SmartWay,Comb CO2

ACURA RDX,3.5,6,SemiAuto-6,2WD,Gasoline,FA,T3B125,Federal Tier 3 Bin 125,JHNXT03.5GV3,small SUV,3,20,28,23,5,No,386
```

```py
import pandas as pd
df_18 = pd.read_csv('file name')
```

request:
Rename all column labels to replace spaces with underscores and convert everything to lowercase.
below code did work, and I don't know why

```
df_18.rename(str.lower().str.strip().str.replace(" ","_"),axis=1,inplace=True)
```

Comment: `df.columns = df.columns.str.lower().str.strip().str.replace(' ', '_')` is the correct way to chain `.str` functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly assign the list of column names to `pandas.DataFrame.columns`; you can perform the required operations i.e. `lower`, `strip`, and `replace` in a list-comprehension for each column names, and assign it back to the `dataframe.columns`

```py
df_18.columns = [col.lower().strip().replace(" ","_") for col  in df_18]
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
       model  displ  cyl  ... greenhouse_gas_score smartway comb_co2
0  ACURA RDX    3.5    6  ...                    5       No      386
[1 rows x 18 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for column in df_18.columns:
    new_column_name = column.lower().strip().replace(" ","_")

    if new_column_name != column:
        df_18[new_column_name] = df_18[column]
        del df_18[column]
```

Comment: This approach has bug. You are deleting the column in the end. If source column is already in lowercase and does not have _, it will get deleted.

Comment: Fair point, edited and added a conditional to prevent that

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to rename the column,

[reference for renaming columns](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-rename-columns-in-pandas-dataframe/)

[reference for replace string](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-replace/)

you can use the below code.

```
df_18.columns=[col.lower().replace(" ","_")  for col in df_18.columns]
```

Comment: i received this as a solution, but i can't understand how did it work

df_18.rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip().lower().replace(" ", "_"), inplace=True)

how did the function got the x attribute?, and how all columns changed

Comment: In rename method of dataframe, column parameter requires, a dictionary i.e., old_value: new_value,  or it can have a function which will map the column name , and inplace=True did changesa as permanent, (default is false) https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html

Comment: i understand the first part, but "or it can have a function which will map the column name" i cant relate it with the previous code!!

Comment: lambda x: x.strip().lower().replace(" ", "_"), this lambda function will get the columns names of df_18, and it will return in the corresponding column name with the lowercase and spaces will be replaced by _